# No problem vs no problem at all

Tags: phrases

If someone asks me to do something, can I answer "no problem at all" or should I say "No problem"? Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: It's all in the intonation and gestures.

Answer (score 1):

"No problem at all" is generally a more emphatic way of saying "no problem". You can use either but be aware of your audience; some people may perceive one or the other, or even both, as being insincere.

Comment: I think this would be a good answer if it were limited to the first and last sentences.

Comment: The problem is that my experience is exactly the opposite of yours: "no problem" tends to be dismissive, while "no problem at all" tends to be enthusiastic. Which of us is right? My view isn't even represented. If I'm right and the OP follows your advice, he may cause inadvertent offense. But what about Joe's view? Or Susie's? Either we cover all the different possible interpretations, or we simply indicate that such differences may exist.

Comment: More even handed, yes. I'm still not convinced your opinion is necessary to the answer.

Comment: That may very well be so, but extending an answer by inserting your personal interpretation does not add any value to it. The OP is highly unlikely to ever meet you. Answers should either cover all relevant facts or be completely general.

Answer (score -1):

"Yes, I can" or "Certainly I can" is a more positive response to the question.  Why introduce the idea that there could be a problem?  Was the person asking you to do something anticipating any problems?  Call me old-fashioned but when people respond to a request I make by saying "No problem" or "No problem at all" I cringe.  A simple yes, accompanied by a confident smile, is all that is required.

P.S. I make no apology for introducing my opinion.  How a person responds to a request to do something absolutely depends on who is asking you. It might be okay to say "No problem" to a colleague or someone your own age and status, but if the request comes from the CEO, for example, or the President, "No problem" won't cut it.